# Is there a way to save BigQuery interactive shell results to file?

Tags: sql, shell, google-bigquery

Doing `bq shell` runs the BigQuery interactive shell. Once run, the shell can accept SQL commands and a tabular format of the results is shown.

Is there a way to save these interactive results to a file (e.g. CSV, JSON, etc...)?

Comment: If the data needs to be saved routinely then you might consider building a custom website using this [starter project](https://github.com/winwiz1/crisp-bigquery). I'm the author. The website is hydrated by a parameterised query and can be modified to support several queries. End users supply query parameters, run queries, paginate through results and save data into a local CSV file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this by using `--format` flag, where you can pass one of the following options:

- pretty - formatted table output
- sparse - simpler table output
- prettyjson - easy-to-read JSON format
- json - maximally compact JSON
- csv - csv format with header

I have tested it with `prettyjson` format and it works fine:

```
bq query --format=prettyjson --use_legacy_sql=false 'SELECT name, number FROM `bigquery-public-data`.usa_names.usa_1910_current WHERE gender = "M" ORDER BY number DESC' > output.json
```

By using `>` at the end of the command, it is possible to save the output of a command to a new file. You will be able to see the output of query in `output.json` file.

Another possible way to do it is writing query results to a permanent table with `bq query` command and then download the results to CSV/JSON.

When you run following example:

```
bq shell
query --use_legacy_sql=false --destination_table project_id:dataset.table 'SELECT name, number FROM `bigquery-public-data`.usa_names.usa_1910_current WHERE gender = "M" ORDER BY number DESC'
```

Remember, that the destination table must be new or empty.

The results of executed query looks like this:

```
Waiting on bqjob_r11abc345 ... (5s) Current status: DONE
+---------+--------+
|  name   | number |
+---------+--------+
| Robert  |  10021 |
| John    |   9636 |
| Robert  |   9297 |
| ...              |
+---------+--------+
```

Now, when you go to BigQuery web UI, you will be able to see results in `project_id:dataset.table`. After you run a SQL query, you can download the results to a file on your local machine, you can save the results to Google Drive or Google Sheets. You can download query results locally only in CSV or newline-delimited JSON format.

I recommend you to take a look for [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/writing-results#writing_query_results). I hope it helps you.

Comment: this doesn't quite answer the question, which is about saving the results of an interactive session _from within_ `bq shell`

Comment: Is it necessary to have a table exists before we run this 'bq shell
query' ?